# Substring of a phrase in a sentence in Java

Tags: java, substring

I want to check if a bunch of words appear in a sentence.Essentially, I need the substring functionality for a phrase.
Instead of the Java substring, I also need to check for a substring between more than one word, and ensure that the match includes only consecutive words in the sentence.
Needless to say,if the phrase itself is one word, then one word match should work. If the phrase is more than one word, then substring should do an exact match in the sentence.

For example, given two sentences "The book was in the other bag", and "In other words, I could not arrive at a conclusion", I need to check if any of them match a phrase "in other words".

Comment: In your example none of the sentences match the phrase, and only one contains it (if you ignore the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `String.contains` method, be aware this is a case sensitive search.

```
String ex1 = "The book was in the other bag";
String ex2 = "In other words, I could not arrive at a conclusion";
String search = "in other words";

ex1.toUpperCase().contains(search.toUpperCase());
ex2.toUpperCase().contains(search.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: I know because of the casing.  That is why I advised about casing in the answer, but I have updated to switch everything over to the same case for the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains()`

Check this examples:

http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-string-contains-example/

Also, if you need to ignore case, you can parse both strings to lower case `str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a regular expression:

```
String str1 = "The book was in the other bag";
String str2 = "In other words, I could not arrive at a conclusion";
String phrase = "in other words";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(phrase, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

boolean str1containsPhrase = pattern.matcher(str1).find(); // false
boolean str2containsPhrase = pattern.matcher(str2).find(); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Class StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html), it offers more flexibility checking for substrings like substring extraction relative to other strings(like [substringBefore](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBefore%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) / [substringAfter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringAfter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) / [substringBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) as [containsAny](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsAny%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20char...%29) / [containsOnly](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsOnly%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20char...%29) and [containsIgnoreCase](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) etc.)